# распилить файл на два файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, существует ли способ сделать разделение файла быстрее, чем написал я?

```
from threading import Thread
from datetime import datetime

def spliter(name):
    now = datetime.now()

    print(f"start spliting at : {now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')}")
    with open(name, "r") as f:
        data = f.readlines()
        sep = int(len(data) / 2)
        first = """"""
        second = """"""

        def dd1():
            nonlocal first
            for i in data[:sep]:
                first += i

        def dd2():
            for i in data[sep:]:
                nonlocal second
                second += i

        t1 = Thread(target=dd1)
        t2 = Thread(target=dd2)
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
        t1.join()
        t2.join()
        file1 = open('first.txt', "w")
        file1.write(first)

        file2 = open('second.txt', "w")
        file2.write(second)
    print(f"end spliting at : {now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    spliter('Price WA.txt')
```

Comment: да, но и в вашем способе можно оптимизировать

Comment: вы имеете ввиду переместить nonlocal в локальные переменные?

Comment: я бы убрал оба цикла

Comment: =))) круто, я нуб можно было сжойнить это, спасибо!

Comment: а можно не жойнить.

Comment: а как иначе можно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цикл убрать, нелокальные переменные можно убрать и остается уже

```
file1 = open('first.txt', "w")
file1.writelines(data[:sep])
```

Треды теперь не нужны. Правда можно....

```
t1 = Thread(target=file1.writelines,args=(data[:sep],))
```

Но не уверен что это даст какой-то особый прирост

Comment: странно, зачем я решил пробежать цыклом по файлу. было 20 мин. теперь 2 сек. спс

Comment: можно ещё быстрее ;)

Comment: не хорош, подождут они две секунды